# Why network drive is not accesible after reboot?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mappeddrive

I have set a network drive on a Windows 2008 that is used by a scheduled task to read some files.

After Windows update, server is rebooted and network drive becomes inaccesible for the task.

What is weird is that if I log in to the server with the same credentials the task runs, I can access network drive without problems.

Once I log in and open the network drive using file explorer, task can access it again. It's like an unblock thing.

What is causing nework drive to be inaccesible on non interactive mode after reboot?

Comment: Have you seen this: [Map a network drive to be used by a service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service)?

Comment: @beatcracker: definitively seems to be related. Thanks :)